# Ending of Eden Lake

Tags: ending, eden-lake

I just watched the movie Eden Lake (2008). It has a very sad and disturbing ending. The bad guy who killed Steve and also burned Adam alive for his disobedience doesn't get any punishment but the lady who accidentally kills a small boy gets killed by Brett's family. What kind of an ending is that? What is the director trying to say to the audience from that ending?

Answer (score 4):

Well, we can't expect every movie to have a happy ending. Sometimes film makers prefer to make movies in an unconventional way. Eden Lake is one of those movies happens to fall under that category with anticlimax, a disappointing ending for the audience, a good example for these type of movies in the recent times is *Gone Girl (2014)*.

Here's what director, James Watkins says about the ending in an [interview](http://www.esplatter.com/news.php?id=1104).

> The most chilling thing about the film may be the ending. Did any of
>   the producers pressure you to give the film an 'happy ending'?
>
> The ending was discussed: so I came up with an even darker ending! You
>   don't want to know…

and in [another](http://marksalisbury.blogspot.in/2008/09/james-watkinseden-lake-q-part-two.html) interview, he says,

> Were there many discussions about the ending?
>
> Yeah, lots of discussions. I didn’t want to have an ending… she’s a
>   school teacher, she’s been through this horrible journey, she’s
>   reached almost this point… you know when she gets the knife and it’s
>   kind of almost pathetic when she hits the dad with the knife and she’s
>   almost at the end of the road I think. **I didn’t want her to turn into
>   this take charge Ripley, Sarah Connor, pull a grenade out of her dress
>   and kill everybody Death Wish**.

From his words, I understand that he doesn't want to end the movie like the most of the slasher flicks that are made in mainstream cinema. But he wants to end it in a much more darker and realistic way.